# SQL Server 2012, triggers, compare rows in inserted and deleted

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a trigger with code:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO schema.table(old_id, old_user, new_id, new_user) 
        SELECT OLD.id, OLD.user, NEW.id, NEW.user
        FROM INSERTED NEW, 
           DELETED OLD 
        WHERE  OLD.id = NEW.id; 
END
```

And it works when id column is at least unique, but how to do it when table does not have unique column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but how to do it when table does not have unique column

Is trivially simple: you add an unique column, or a combination of unique columns, enforced by a primary key constraint. Nothing else will work. Ever.